Error While Adding WhatsApp Business API Payment Method
I'm trying to integrate a payment method using the WhatsApp Business API, but I'm encountering an issue. Whenever I attempt to add the payment method, I receive the following error message:
"We're having trouble completing your request."
Image1
Image2
Image3

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
